# can't see highlight color in regedit

Tags: windows-7, regedit

I do a "Find" in regedit and when it finds the item, I can barely see which one it is in the left window.  Is there a way to change the highlight color?  I've tried editing the theme but it doesn't seem to make any changes to this particular item.

Can you see from the image which one I searched?  It's last from the bottom. In a certain light, you can't see the difference between the ones above and below it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? You should be able to see the highlighted item. Note, although you do not have sufficient reputation to post images yet, if you post a link, someone with sufficient reputation will edit in the image for you.

Comment: You mention theme, but have you tried changing the the custom color for the desktop background?

Comment: @LPChip, "should" is the operative word here, which is why I posted this. Not sure how to link from here to an image on my desktop, nor do I want to. Is there a file cabinet on the site?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, desktop color is set to Twilight (royal blue) with the intensity slider set 3/4 of the way to the right. Not sure what that has to do with the regedit directory.

Comment: The background color and other desktop colors affect colors of highlights, taskbar etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to `咲くやこの花` Answer in this post: [How to change the highlight color properly / permanently?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_general/how-to-change-the-highlight-color-properly/b720d88a-8ff6-4ca3-8815-c66e2d9f2c29)

The registry path of highlight/highlight is:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\DefaultColors\Standard`

And we can refer to the following value.
Earlier releases used light blue Hilight(version 1607).

(a): REG_SZ = `"51 153 255"` (Red=51, Green=153, Blue=255)
(b): REG_DWORD = `00ff9933` (Blue=FF(255), Green=99(153), Red=33(51))

Newer releases use dark blue Hilight(version 1703 and later).

(c): REG_SZ = "`0 120 215`" (Red=0, Green=120, Blue=215)
(d): REG_DWORD = `00d77800` (Blue=D7(215), Green=78(120), Red=00(0))

Comment: not what I'm asking.